# Как можно на Python обрезать строку и выбрать конкретное значение по аналогии с Bash

Tags: python, строки, bash, snmp

Как можно на Python обрезать строку и выбрать конкретное значение по аналогии с Bash.
Есть код на Bash такой

```
hw=$(snmpget -Lo -v2c -c public $ip $cr_chassis_oid | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | sed -E 's/[cC]hassis.*$//g')
```

И вот этот код нужно по аналогии сделать на Python. Но я не нашёл аналогичных функций для работы со строками.
А нужно вот из таких строк:

```
2811 chassis
CISCO2911R/K9 chassis, Hw Serial#: JTV2114TKYH, Hw Revision: 1.0
Cisco ISR4331 Chassis
3845 chassis
```

получить значения: 2811, 2911R/K9, ISR4331, 3845 и т.д.

Comment: Вы плохо искали. Попробуйте запустить браузер, ввести google.com и поискать там.

Comment: string.split(' ')[0]

Comment: хороший вариант. Если доработать, то будет годно. Спасибо

Comment: `cat файл | python -c "import sys,re;[sys.stdout.write(re.sub('^cisco ?','',re.sub(r'[cC]hassis.*$','',line),flags=re.IGNORECASE)) for line in sys.stdin]"`

Comment: у Вас тоже интересный вариант, но я решил немного легче:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

вот как я сам смог решить этот вопрос:

```
# из этого нужно получить chassis
str2 = "CISCO2911R/K9 chassis, Hw Serial#: --------, Hw Revision: 1.0" 
# убираем пробелы
str7 = str2.replace(' ','')
# обрезаем всё лишнее
print (str(str7[5:(str7.lower().rfind(str5))]))
```